# Java Generics use

Tags: java, generics

```
public class A implements SomeInterface<B>{
    ...
    class B{
     ....
    }
 ....
}
```

`Class B` is declared in `class A` so when I write `SomeInterface<B>` would it work although B is declared only in A?

Comment: This isn't called template in Java.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: As suggested by aix you can see yourself by trying. The question is: what are you trying to do? If you explain your goal and what you've tried, someone here may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
interface SomeInterface <T> {
    void doing (T t);
}

public class A implements SomeInterface <A.B> {
    public void doing (A.B ab) {}
    class B {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem conceptually.

---

As far as syntax is concerned, `B` cannot be directly referenced outside `A`'s body without `import`

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3

"The scope of a declaration of a member m declared in .. a class type C is the entire body of C"

So these are illegal

```
@Anno(M.class)  // illegal
class C implements X<M>  // illegal
      class M
```

However I think that is too restrictive; it could have been extended a little more. Consider

```
@Anno(C.class)  // legal
class C implements X<C>  // legal
```

that's because the scope of the top level class `C` is the entire "type declaration", which is bigger than mere "entire body". There is no reason why we couldn't extend M's scrope to be "the entire type declaration of C" as well.

See also [Static inner classes need import for annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800581/static-inner-classes-need-import-for-annotations/4801256)

Comment: Well...user unknown's answer shows that it *is* possible so what specifically is your conclusion "no" referring to?  And what does this have to do with annotations?

Comment: @Mark Peters `A.B` is not `B`.

Comment: @irreputable: It *is* the same referant, but I just wanted to make sure your conclusion was based on the exact code the OP gave and not whether what he was trying to do was possible.

Comment: @Mark Peters OP wants to reference B directly outside A's body. That's impossible. (well... possible with `import A.B` in A.java. but that's ridiculous)

Comment: @Mark Peters ok I get it - you think the issue is semantics, I think the issue is syntactic. Of course `B` can be referenced outside `A`, - but not in the syntax given by OP.

Comment: @irreputable: I don't think it's entirely ridiculous, at least not in the general case.  I could imagine `Map` legitimately implementing `Iterable<Map.Entry>`, for example.  The OP's specific example seems a bit contrived.  Either way, the import's not needed, you just need to qualify B with A.  Thanks for the JLS perspective regarding the syntax.

Comment: @Mark Peters I was only focusing on syntax, whether the simple name `B` can be referenced that way.